# build docker image with or without sudo?

Tags: sudo, docker, container

I have a really simple doubt but could not find an exhaustive answer anywhere.

When I build a docker image is it a good practice to build it with `sudo`? If yes, why? and why not?

i.e. should I do:

`sudo docker build -t DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME .`

or just

`docker build -t DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME .`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion based. The docker daemon itself usually runs as root, and that's what actually does the building. So this question just devolves into a debate in giving access to docker directly or via sudo, which AFAIAC is fully an opinion poll with some security theatre added on top

Comment: Ok, thanks for your opinion about this. I thought that there was a more unique answer to my question and did not mean to start a poll.

Comment: It really shouldn't matter at all. The normal practice nowadays is to add your user to the `docker` group and just run as that user - so this should be equally viable here.